# Ошибся при переустановке windows, помогите пожалуйста!

Tags: windows

В общем решил с 10 на 7 перейти. Сделал загрузочную флешку. В Биосе ставлю legacy, делаю перезагрузку. Идёт установочное меню, и на этапе выборе жёсткого диска, проблема была в том что жеский диск был со сферой got. Я удалил все другие разделы как говорили на форумах с похожими проблемами, и через ф 10 шифт через строку поменял на dmc (вроде так). Правда позже пошла проблема уже не помню как точно написать но в общем там типо х000003010 ошибка и ещё немного текста. Ярешил перезагрузить, перезагрузил и теперь дальше биоса, не идёт, чёрный экран с текстом
No bootable device — insert boot disk and press any key, и дальше при нажатии любой кнопки такое же. Флешка суперновая, сегодня купил на 32, она все ещё стоит в приводе. Винда отличная, лучшие отзывы о сборке у всех все норм, делал флешку через ультраИсо. Флешка в приводе когда вылизиет чёрный экран. Вынимаю ничего не происходит. Я удалил все другие жёсткие диски и оставил 1 а его форматнул, так что восстановление не получиться.
Ноутбук Acer e 15. Core i3 - 6006u gtx940mx, 4gb[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Включи обратно efi и не трожь (или верни) gpt. Ну и что случилось с данными на всём диске (именно диске, а не разделе) после твоих манипуляций - неизвестно. Попробуй загрузиться с линуксовой флешки и посмотреть. Возможно, стоит сделать образ перед дальнейшими манипуляциями.

Comment: 1. С MBR точно всё будет ок. 2. "Винда отличная, лучшие отзывы о сборке у всех все норм" - откуда у всех такая любовь к сборкам? Что трудного в том, чтобы самостоятельно взять и всё настроить в ванили? 3. Ты снёс всё превсё включая загрузчики и таблицы разделов?